# android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" is not showing any effect in Modal

Tags: react-native, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

when any `TxtInput` is focused, Then keyboard will push the bottom buttons as keyboard comes up. But his behaviour can be avoided with this line,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

But this line is showing effect in normal pages only but not in Modals.

Is there anything to do besides to above mentioned line to have the desired output in Modals as well?. Thank You.

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @sewb not yet .